# How can I add a class to a parent element if the child element's value is greater than zero?

Tags: jquery, parent-child, addclass

I've got a shopping cart that produces the following code:

```
<a href="/cart/" class="et-cart-info">
  <span>1</span><!-- cart contents number -->
</a>
```

When a user has an item, I would like the class `.yipi` added to `.et-cart-info`. When it's empty and shows `<span>0</span>` I want the class removed.

I've tried the following code but no avail:

```
jQuery(function($){
    var amount = $(".et-cart-info span").val();
  if( amount >= '1' ) {
      $(".et-cart-info").addClass('yipi');
  }
});
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get the text content of the span, not val().

```
jQuery(function($){
  var amount = $(".et-cart-info span").text();
  if( amount >= '1' ) {
    $(".et-cart-info").addClass('yipi');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
jQuery(function($){
        var amount = $(".et-cart-info span").html();
      if( Number(amount) >= 1 ) {
          $("a.et-cart-info").addClass('yipi');
      }
    });
```